# @ResponseBody not working in spring 3.2.5 got 406 error

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I am upgrade my spring framwork 2 to 3.2.5 @ResponseBody not working.
In lib folder there are

> **jackson-core-asl-1.9.9  jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9** also avaliable.

Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/addCompany",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Company addCompany(HttpServletResponse response)
{

    LOG.info("ADD COMPPUNY SUCCESS");
    Company company=new Company();
    company.setCompanyEmail("subhash lamba");
    return company;
    //return new JSONObject(company).toString();

}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property> 

    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">


    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I got error like

[image]

I try lots of solution but those are not working for me, Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't need anything from this configuration. `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is even deprecated. It is strongly recommended to use Jackson 2.x.

Comment: now what can i do for now? please help me to solve this problem. even i remove those configuration then also it is not working. please help me to solve this problem

Comment: In your ajax call it has to be `dataType` with a capital T.

Comment: i write it but it is not working.

Comment: Set your log level to debug for org.springframework.web and look at what Spring tells you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things ... What's in the logs ? What was the http request ? Also you kind of have a hint about the Accept headers. I'd definitely be looking for a specific Exception. I'm pretty sure you'll find one.

Use something like firebug to examine the Accept headers. If I may make a suggestion, springmvc-test-framework can help a bunch here as well. It may take a while to get set up properly but is invaluable longer term.

So those are general recommendations to solve the problem.

Comment: this is by ajax to call. there is nothing in LOG just call controller successfully.  <br><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/admin/addCompany.html",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {status:'0'},
    datatype:"json",
    success:function(data) 
    {
     
     if(data=="success")
    {
      $("#PriorityDiv").html($("#PriorityOption option:selected").text());
    }
     endLoading();
    }
  });
      });
      
      </script>
<body>

Comment: If i change return type from object to string then it working but at that time i need to convert my object to JSON manually.

Answer (score 0):

Add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your `@RequestMapping`.

In your ajax call change `datatype` to `dataType`. And if it still doesn't work add

```
accepts: { json: 'application/json' }
```

Nothing of that should be necessary if everything's set up properly. So maybe there is some configuration error.